# Badges in stackexchange

Tags: discussion

Yesterday, I honored to receive a yearling silver badge for staying as an Active member for a year ago.

I'm so happy and proud to share my humble knowledge here, and I love this community for a degree I am staying here more than staying with my close friends.

So I would like to suggest some notes related to a specific area that I noticed during this year!

- There is no badge for top contributors (bronze) week/(Silver) Month/(Gold)Quarter/Year. PS. At least (Top 5) contributors.
- The Social channels like twitter don't care about announcing the top contributors per week, month, quarter, year.
- There is no SE-MVP award per quarter/year for top contributors. or at least receiving a simple encourage email or a bit mention in twitter.

I don't know if I have the right to talk about this or not, I just appreciate this community and appreciate all new enhancements and hope the continued success.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting idea, but since there are no SharePoint specific badges, I guess the place to ask this question would be at the general Meta site https://meta.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Benny for your precious feedback and your usual support!

Answer (score 3):

Problem with the badges/ranking model is that people with many points get even more points.

If you analyse the Top-All , many of them have not participated for over a year.

[image]

Better system would be if points/likes/rewards degrade,
because let's be honest, a SP2010 question that got 100+ points 10 years ago is (most of the time) of no value to the current community

So the whole 'scoring' is askew, 10 years ago getting a dozen +1s on an answer wasn't uncommon. If you get 2 now it is a lot.

But like Benny said, that's up to StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks !!!......

Comment: Code at: https://github.com/Danny-Engelman/StackOverflow-UserActivity